# What is the best tool to use to transfer Data from Reporting Database to another?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a reporting database and have to transfer data from that to another server where we run some other reports or functions on Data. What is the best way to transfer data periodically like months or by-weekly. I can use SSIS but is there anyway I can put some where clause on what rows should be extracted from the source database? like i only want to extract data for a current month. Please do let me know.

Thanks,
Vivek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For scheduling periodic extractions, I'd leave to that SQL Agent.

As for restricting the results by some condition, that's an easy thing. Instead of this (and you should always use SQL Command or SQL Command From Variable over Table Name/Table Name From Variable as they are faster) 
[image]

Add a parameter. If you're use OLE DB connection manager, your indicator for a variable is `?`. ADO.NET will be `@parameterName`

[image]

Now, wire the filter up by clicking the Parameters... button. With OLE DB, it's ordinal position starting at 0. If you wanted to use the same parameter twice, you will have to list it each time or use the ADO.NET connection manager.

[image]

The biggest question you will have to answer is how do I identify what row(s) need to go. Possibilities are endless: query into the target database and find most recent modified date for a table or highest key value. You could create a local table that tracks what's been sent and query that. You could perform an [incremental load](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72494/) / [ETL Instrumentation](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andy_leonard/archive/2007/11/18/ssis-design-pattern-etl-instrumentation-part-3.aspx) to identify new/updated/unchanged rows, etc.